# HTML5 Columns with content going left to right

Tags: html, css, layout

I am working on an image gallery project, and I'm using the code found here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout to make columns.

I'm fetching the images from reddit, 30 at a time, and putting them in three columns. I want the first three images to be closest to the top, but right now they are all going down the left-most column. Basically I'm getting

```
1   11   21
2   12   22
3   13   23
4   14   24
5   15   25
6   16   26
7   17   27
8   18   28
9   19   29
10  20   30
```

But what I want is

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
10   11   12
13   14   15
16   17   18
19   20   21
22   23   24
25   26   27
28   29   30
```

More or less. The images are all different heights. Like as each image comes along, it gets places in the column that is currently shortest.

Any way to do this that still uses css columns?

Comment: It's all in the browser, so javascript. With css and html, of course. Check the link.

Comment: column css won't do, but float + nth-child(3n+1) {clear) will dispatch items on row of three floatting elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `float`, `nth-child` & `clear`: example with a list

```
li {
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:2em;
}
li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear:left;
}
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KfsLc

Comment: This is kind of close. The problem with this solution is some images are much taller than others. With css columns, each image goes right below the one above. With this solution if there is a tall image it pushes the entire next row down.

Comment: okay, then you should take a look at the masonry script http://masonry.desandro.com/